# MySQL is too slow on Windows VPS

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, vps, wordpress, mysql5.5

I'm running a wordpress blog on my VPS, But MySQL Queries are taking too much time.

For example, it is taking more than 1.5 seconds to load a post from database.

But CPU and RAM usage is low on my server. I've 2GB RAM, and 1.2GB of it is free right now. also CPU usage is below 5%.

I'm running `IIS 7.5` on `Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter edition (64-bit)`, with `MySQL 5.5` installed on it. (Also there is MS SQL 2012 Express installed on the machine, but it's inactive most of times)

PHP is running fast on my server, but MySQL queries seems to be too slow.

Also I've tried optimizing database from phpmyadmin, and speed becomes a little better, but still it's too slow.

Is this normal on a Windows VPS? How to improve MySQL performance?

**Update:** I've read somewhere that `127.0.0.1` as the host works better than `localhost`, and I'm using `127.0.0.1` now, but still database queries are too slow.

**Update 2:** This is the HDD benchmark on my VPS:

[image: HDD Benchmark]

Also there is report of another HDD benchmark tool:

- Read 50 MB file with 256 KB buffer:

> Reading 52,428,800 B (50 MB)  - 200 blocks
>
> Success: 52,428,800 B (50 MB)
>
> Time: 1.329
>
> Speed:  39,463,373 B/sec (37.6 MB/sec)

- Read 50 MB file with 32 KB buffer:

> Reading 52,428,800 B (50 MB)  - 1,600 blocks
>
> Success: 52,428,800 B (50 MB)
>
> Time: 10.873
>
> Speed:  4,821,734 B/sec (4.6 MB/sec)

- Read 50 MB file with 1 KB buffer:

> Reading 52,428,800 B (50 MB)  - 51,200 blocks
>
> Success: 52,428,800 B (50 MB)
>
> Time: 1:06.395
>
> Speed:  789,648 B/sec (771 KB/sec)

Comment: You've mentioned memory and CPU usage. How about disk? My bet is that your underlying disk is being slammed by the other systems you're sharing hardware with. Fire up some disk resource monitors...

Comment: Important metrics are read/write latency and how much time the CPU is spending waiting for io.

Comment: Exactly. Pretty often, discs are the problem. And databases need fast disc IO. A dprocess waiting for the disc can not work. Is it normal on windows? No. Is it normal on underpowered cheap VPS? Yes. i dont ahve a single VPS hosting server with less than 8 physical discs attached (except those obviously booting via network from a SAN).

Comment: @EEAA Question updated with HDD benchmark details

Comment: @TomTom Question updated with HDD benchmark details.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi No, sorry. Get proper random IO bencahmarks on a sensible data set that result in a representative IOPS number. These tests tell nothing - well, except your discs are slow. easure latency per Performance Counters. SHould be low 1 Digit. This smells like seriously slow disc System. Obviously - Performance costs Money.

Comment: @TomTom I couldn't find a benchmark tool that determinates IOPS number. Can you suggest me such application?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is something as simple as tables not being properly indexed. Take a few of your slow running queries and run an EXPLAIN on them to see how many rows are being examined each time.

Also the 127.0.0.1 vs localhost is true as it saves a DNS lookup but judging by what you're describing this is not likely to be the problem.

Comment: Possibly. Would not be the first time.